# xsd schema not working against the xml file

Tags: xml, xsd

having a nightmare here with XSD and XML. Got 1 simple xml file (representing my table in database) and a XSD Schema, I was trying to validate them against each other, and every single time some errors come up. The best thing is different validators show totally different errors on the same files. This first time I'm dealing with this and have no experience with XML. Could someone please point out my errors correctly and briefly explain them? I'm not looking for you guys doing it all for me. Just put me in the right direction.
Thanks, Andy

XSD Schema

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
           xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Users">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="user">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="userID">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="firstName">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])*"/>
                    <xs:minLength value="2"/>
                    <xs:maxLength value="28"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="lastName">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])*"/>
                    <xs:minLength value="2"/>
                    <xs:maxLength value="28"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="email">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"/>
                    <xs:minLength value="6"/>
                    <xs:maxLength value="80"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="DOB">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="tellNo">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] "/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="userTypeID">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="120"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

XML file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Users xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="user.xsd">

  <user userid="1">
        <firstName>Andrew</firstName>
        <lastName>Golota</lastName>
        <email>a.golota@wbc.us</email>
        <DOB>1964-10-24</DOB>
        <tellNo>078222446589</tellNo>
        <userTypeID>1</userTypeID>
    </user>

    <user userid="13">
        <firstName>Barrack</firstName>
        <lastName>Obama</lastName>
        <email>b.obama@whitehouse.us</email>
        <DOB>1970-08-12</DOB>
        <tellNo>079886365212</tellNo>
        <userTypeID>3</userTypeID>
    </user>

    <user userid="11">
        <firstName>Bill</firstName>
        <lastName>Clinton</lastName>
        <email>b.clinton@whitehouse.us</email>
        <DOB>1960-12-07</DOB>
        <tellNo>078537278867</tellNo>
        <userTypeID>2</userTypeID>
    </user>

    <user userid="5">
        <firstName>Michael</firstName>
        <lastName>Grant</lastName>
        <email>m.grant1966@wbc.us</email>
        <DOB>1966-03-08</DOB>
        <tellNo>078339789608</tellNo>
        <userTypeID>4</userTypeID>
    </user>

    <user userid="2">
        <firstName>Mike</firstName>
        <lastName>Tyson</lastName>
        <email>m.tyson@wbc.us</email>
        <DOB>1966-12-01</DOB>
        <tellNo>076255545422</tellNo>
        <userTypeID>1</userTypeID>
    </user>

    <user userid="4">
        <firstName>Mike</firstName>
        <lastName>Mollo</lastName>
        <email>m.mollo@wbc.us</email>
        <DOB>1970-09-07</DOB>
        <tellNo>076255545117</tellNo>
        <userTypeID>3</userTypeID>
    </user>

    <user userid="12">
        <firstName>Monica</firstName>
        <lastName>Levinsky</lastName>
        <email>m.levinsky@slutload.com</email>
        <DOB>1988-12-06</DOB>
        <tellNo>078553323285</tellNo>
        <userTypeID>1</userTypeID>
    </user>

    <user userid="14">
        <firstName>Osama</firstName>
        <lastName>BinLaden</lastName>
        <email>o.binladen@hideout.com</email>
        <DOB>1926-06-06</DOB>
        <tellNo>078552592921</tellNo>
        <userTypeID>2</userTypeID>
    </user>

    <user userid="3">
        <firstName>Riddick</firstName>
        <lastName>Bowe</lastName>
        <email>r.bowe@wbc.us</email>
        <DOB>1962-02-14</DOB>
        <tellNo>078222556575</tellNo>
        <userTypeID>2</userTypeID>
    </user>

    <user userid="0">
        <firstName>Tomasz</firstName>
        <lastName>Adamek</lastName>
        <email>t.adamek@wbc.us</email>
        <DOB>1970-04-04</DOB>
        <tellNo>077456757842</tellNo>
        <userTypeID>1</userTypeID>
    </user>

</Users>
```

Comment: my las error says Cvc-elt.1: Cannot Find The Declaration Of Element 'Users'.. Line '2', Column '45'.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be because of the `targetNamespace` which is set to `"http://www.w3schools.com"` in your schema, but not in your XML instance.

2 solutions :

1. either your need this namespace, and you have to set in your XML:

   ```
    <Users xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="user.xsd"
        xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com">
   ```
2. you don't need it and you can discard it in your schema, and modify it like this :

   ```
   <xs:schema version="1.0"
       xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
   ```

You will notice you have a bunch of new errors, because the attribute `userid` isn't declared (actually you declared a tag), and so on...

PS: Barack Obama is written with a single 'r'... :)